# How should I save state of Fragment that contain a listview on android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

In my app there are two fragments and one activity. On all of  them I used listview and fill the content from database. When rotate screen the position of content in activity don't change and start on   correct way (as I googled and understand it is normal for activity because of "Bundle savedInstanceState"). My problem is with fragment part that both of the list on fragments are too long list and it could be annoying for end user when press back and came back to fragments start navigate to appropriate item. I googled and find some answer to my question but they don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the states saving or restoring won't work anymore, because the listview was dynamically fill up by database or internet. when I facing this problem, I have a long size dataset for that listview, the rest datasets are coming because my data was show as pagination mode, user may scroll out far from first page, so when fragment destroying, all you can do just save the particular parameters to **State Bundle**, e.g. `the page number`, `the selection index`, `the selection y-axis`, finally restore the state by your own hands.